# How find max value in sql server 2008 with one more condition

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

```
PinID      PinType     PinNumber
================================
1             A            125
2             CC           126
3             BB            1
4             JJ           127
5             oo           128
6             NN           2
7             ll           129
8             FF           3
```

this is my table(PinTbl) and as per my requirement i need to find max pinNumber but less than 125, the answer is 3 how can find it ?

I am new to sql server may this question easy but I am unable to find any help on web.

Comment: Have you even made an attempt? What would you do if you wanted to just find the max, could you do that? What would you do if you wanted all rows where PinNumber < 125, could you do that?

Comment: `select max(PinNumber) from PinTbl where PinNumber < 125`

Comment: With PinNumbr do you want to show additional columns like PinID and PinType ?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever To find max I use "select max(PinNumber) from PinTbl" but now I canunderstand using " where < 125" I can solveproblem.

Comment: @KhorshedAlam no I don't need to find out additional columns

Comment: I find it hard to believe that you've done any searching on the web or basic tutorials on SQL that *don't* discuss the `where` clause.

Comment: @ Damien_The_Unbeliever Yes I use where more time but I use it only for string like "select PinNumber from PinTbl where PinType = 'BB' " like that, but I never think to use where with max

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `WHERE` clause to give the condition.

**Query**

```
select max(PinNumber)
from your_table_name
where PinNumber < 125;
```